# Trying to setup GatsbyJS development server on Amazon EC2

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, port-forwarding, localhost

I have an amazon ec2 instance with the following securitiy group

[image]

I am running nginx with the following configuration under `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name http://90342809.compute-1.amazonaws.com/;
location / {
proxy_pass http://90342809.compute-1.amazonaws.com/:8000;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
}
```

If I run `sudo netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN I get the following

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      14051/nginx: master 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      670/systemd-resolve 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1094/sshd           
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1094/sshd
```

and lastly my gatsby app is running at http://localhost:8000

I am getting connection refused when I visit the url whether I put port 8000 behind it or not.

ANy help would be greatly appreciated.

I Also have tried running with apache but no luck

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      670/systemd-resolve 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1094/sshd           
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      23067/apache2       
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1094/sshd
```

I even tried a new instance created a node express app, ran it on port 3000 and used the following security group and still no luck
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it was my security group I needed to open custom tcp to 3000 to anything instead of the security group for the node app. Got something working now.